# MVC5 with EF many to many when deleting

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two entity Material and Supplier,because of the relation I create a middle entity `MaterialWithSuppliers`:

```
[Key]
[StringLength(150)]
public string Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Material")]
public string MaterialNo { get; set; }
public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Supplier")]
public int SupplierId { get; set; }
public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
```

when I try to delete one record in Material, I have to delete the record in `MaterialWithSuppliers` firstly, but strange things happens after I try to delete it like this:

```
var MaterialWithSupplier = db.MaterialWithSuppliers.Where(m => m.MaterialNo == MaterialNo).ToList();
if (MaterialWithSupplier.Count > 0)
    db.MaterialWithSuppliers.Remove(MaterialWithSupplier[0]);
```

All the records in `MaterialWithSuppliers` have been deleted. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly:

```
var mws = db.MaterialWithSuppliers.Where(m => m.MaterialNo == MaterialNo);
var material = mws.FirstOrDefault()?.Material;
db.MaterialWithSuppliers.RemoveRange(mws);
if (material != null) 
{ 
    db.Materials.Remove(material);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Firstly, you have to retrieve **all** objects, that you want to **remove** from `MaterialWithSuppliers` table.
Secondly, **find** the `material` entity and delete it.

Finally, **save** changes in your database.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have tried your method ,but not only all the records in MaterialWithSuppliers are gone ,but also all the records in Material are gone

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that:`modelBuilder.Entity<Material>().MapToStoredProcedures();`
after I drop this line ,it works normally